# Outer difference along axis in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a tensor T_0 of shape (I,J,K), I am trying to think of an efficient way to construct a new tensor T_1 of shape (I,I,J,K), whose elements are T_1[i1, i2, j, k] = T_0[i1, j, k] - T_0[i2, j, k]

Here is a pedestrian approach with 2 loops:

```
outer_list = [None] * I
for i1 in range(I):
    inner_list = [0] * I
    for i2 in range(I):
        inner_list[i2] = T_0[i1] - T_0[i2]

    outer_list [cl] = tf.stack(tf.stack(inner_list))

T_1 = tf.stack(outer_list )
```

Here is a pedestrian approach with 1 loop:

```
outer_list = [None] * I
for i1 in range(I):
    outer_list[i1] = T_0[i1 : i1+1] - T_0
T_1 = tf.stack(outer_list )
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your requirement because we are not clear how Subtraction between Two Tensors with 3 Dimensions, `(i1, J, K)` and `(i2, J, K)` will result in a Tensor with 4 Dimensions, `(i1, i2, J, K)`. Thanks!